optimising c values to curve fit
I have the code below that solves for the non-dimensional natural frequencies of a beam and then dimensionalises it. I need to use the first frequency mode to fit the curve to experimental data by optimising the c1, c2, c3, and c4 values, but I'm not sure where to start and everything i have tried so far has produced errors and incorrect values.
pdata = np.array([0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0])
fdata = np.array([31786.90305, 33344.70228, 34007.47212, 34388.51794, 34640.69891, 34822.00471, 34959.70061, 35068.44216, 35156.86945, 35230.43423])

L = 0.0067  # Protruding length in meters
rw = 0.005  # Shank radius in meters
Rw = 0.01848 / 2  # Nut radius in meters

E = 200e9  # Pa (Young's Modulus)
I = 4.908738521234052e-10  # m^4 (Moment of Inertia)
rho = 7850  # kg/m^3 (Density)
A = 7.853981633974483e-05  # m^2 (Cross-sectional Area)

def create_Amat(eqns, vars):
    Amat = sp.zeros(len(eqns), len(vars))
    for i, eqn in enumerate(eqns):
        for j, var in enumerate(vars):
            Amat[i, j] = sp.diff(eqn, var)
    return Amat

def CBmodel_T(kt, kr, p):
    # Defining symbolic variables that will be used
    a1, a2, a3, a4, x, beta, omega = sp.symbols('a1 a2 a3 a4 x beta omega')

    # The Genereal Solution for free vibrations in a beam
    GS = a1 * sp.cos(beta * x) + a2 * sp.sin(beta * x) + a3 * sp.cosh(beta * x) + a4 * sp.sinh(beta * x)

    # Defining differentials of the General Solution equation
    # Left Hand Side (x=0)
    Y = GS
    Y1 = sp.diff(Y, x)
    Y2 = sp.diff(Y1, x)
    Y3 = sp.diff(Y2, x)

    # Right Hand Side (x=1)
    D = GS
    D1 = sp.diff(D, x)
    D2 = sp.diff(D1, x)
    D3 = sp.diff(D2, x)

    # Substituting values of x into the differentials
    #Left Hand Side (x=0)
    Y_0 = Y.subs(x, 0)
    Y_1 = Y1.subs(x, 0)
    Y_2 = Y2.subs(x, 0)
    Y_3 = Y3.subs(x, 0)

    # Right Hand Side (x=1)
    D_0 = D.subs(x, 1)
    D_1 = D1.subs(x, 1)
    D_2 = D2.subs(x, 1)
    D_3 = D3.subs(x, 1)

    # Defining Boundary Conditions for the system
    BC1 = Y_3 + kt * Y_0 - p * Y_1
    BC2 = Y_2 - kr * Y_1
    BC3 = D_2
    BC4 = D_3

    # Forming a matrix that contains only the coefficients
    # from the G.S. equation to find the non-trivial solution
    BCs = [BC1, BC2, BC3, BC4]
    var = [a1, a2, a3, a4]

    Amat = create_Amat(BCs, var)

    # Defining the symbolic variable for beta
    beta_sym = sp.sqrt(abs(omega))

    # Substitute symbolic values for beta1, kt, and kr into Amat
    Amat_numeric = Amat.subs({beta: beta_sym, kt: kt, kr: kr})

    # Find the determinant of Amat
    Amat_numeric = sp.simplify(sp.det(Amat_numeric))

    # Convert Amat_numeric to a function handle
    f_omega = lambdify(omega, Amat_numeric, 'numpy')

    # An empty array to store the roots
    n = []

    # Iterate through ranges of initial values for omega
    for j in range(0, 350, 1):
        bracket = [j, j + 1]
        try:
            result = root_scalar(f_omega, bracket=bracket)
            if result.converged and np.sign(f_omega(bracket[0])) != np.sign(f_omega(bracket[1])):
                n.append(result.root)
        except ValueError:
            # Ignore ValueError (f(a) and f(b) must have different signs)
            pass

    # Sorts and removes nonreal numbers
    n = np.array(n)
    n = n[n == np.real(n)]
    n = np.round(n[n == np.real(n)], decimals=10)
    n = np.unique(n)

    if kt == 0 or kr == 0:
        n = n[n > -1]
    
    else:
        n = n[n > 0]
    
    # Extract the first 5 unique values
    w1, w2, w3, w4, w5 = n[:5]

    # Return the non-dimensional frequencies
    return w1, w2, w3, w4, w5

def dimensionalise(w1, w2, w3, w4, w5, E, I, L, rho, A):

    # Equation used to dimensionalise each nondimensional natural frequency
    f1 = w1 * (1/(2*np.pi)) * np.sqrt((E * I) / (rho * A * L**4))
    f2 = w2 * (1/(2*np.pi)) * np.sqrt((E * I) / (rho * A * L**4))
    f3 = w3 * (1/(2*np.pi)) * np.sqrt((E * I) / (rho * A * L**4))
    f4 = w4 * (1/(2*np.pi)) * np.sqrt((E * I) / (rho * A * L**4))
    f5 = w5 * (1/(2*np.pi)) * np.sqrt((E * I) / (rho * A * L**4))

    # Return the dimensionalised frequencies
    return f1, f2, f3, f4, f5

def stiffnessfunction(p,L,rw,Rw,c1,c2,c3,c4):
    #Pre-allocate arrays for stiffness values
    kt = np.zeros_like(p)
    kr = np.zeros_like(p)

    #Normal/tangential stiffness
    kn = (c1*np.tanh(c2*p))/(1+(c3*np.exp(-c4*p)))

    #Constant parameters
    ct = ((np.pi/2)*(1-0.3))/(2-0.3)
    cr = (1/4)*((Rw**2+rw**2)/(L**2))

    #Translational and rotational stiffness parameters
    kt = ct*kn
    kr = cr*kn

    return kt, kr


What is the precise problem with the code? What have you ruled out as causes? What is the expected and actual output produced? Also make sure you provide a [mcve] that everyone can run to reproduce the issue. As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

This is what I have attempted to use but it hasn't worked.
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import differential_evolution

# Constants for kt and kr calculations
ct = ((np.pi/2) * (1 - 0.3)) / (2 - 0.3)
cr = (1/4) * ((0.00924**2 + 0.005**2) / (0.0067**2))

# Define the determinant function using numpy operations
def det_function(c, beta, p):
    c1, c2, c3, c4 = c
    kn = (c1 * np.tanh(c2 * p)) / (1 + c3 * np.exp(-c4 * p))
    kt = ct * kn
    kr = cr * kn
    return abs(-(2 * beta**6 * np.cos(beta) * np.cosh(beta) - 2 * beta**6) * kt * kr +
           (2 * beta**7 * np.sin(beta) * np.cosh(beta) - 2 * beta**7 * np.cos(beta) * np.sinh(beta)) * kt +
           (2 * beta**9 * np.sin(beta) * np.cosh(beta) + 2 * beta**9 * np.cos(beta) * np.sinh(beta)) * kr +
           2 * beta**10 * (np.cos(beta) * np.cosh(beta) - 1) + 
           2 * beta**8 * p * np.sin(beta) * np.sinh(beta))

# Function to calculate the sum of determinants
def sum_of_determinants(c):
    total_det = 0
    for beta_val in beta_values:
        for p_val in pdata:
            total_det += det_function(c, beta_val, p_val)
    return total_det

# Bounds for the parameters
parameter_bounds = [(0.01, 25000), (0.01, 250), (0.01, 250), (0.01, 250)]

# Perform optimization
result = differential_evolution(sum_of_determinants, parameter_bounds, strategy='best1bin', maxiter=1000, popsize=15, tol=0.01, mutation=(0.5, 1), recombination=0.7)

# Print the result
print("Optimal parameters:", result.x)
print("Minimum sum of absolute determinants:", result.fun)

